# Comparison of methods with bias

Tags: bias, method-comparison

In a planned study where I am supposed to assist, the goal is to measure the agreement between on one hand the results from an activity measurement device and on the other self-reported values. Both instruments are meant to measure physical activity in minutes.

The instruments could not be expected to be particularly precise, but they could still be consistent with each other. My question now is how the degree of consistency could be studied? I don't even know what terms I should be looking for. Simple correlation is naturally not an option, and most methods for measuring agreement seem to be based on the assumption that all methods are on target and measure the same underlying variable. In this case, I would like to see if the methods are reasonably consistent, and possibly also to quantify the bias. Any suggestions?

Robert

Comment: You have both types of measurement (from the device & self-reported) on each individual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have both types of measurement on each individual then the sample of differences contains all the answers.  You can calculate the mean square error, decompose it into bias (the mean of the differences) and variance, & also look for outliers, differences between subgroups, & so on.